# Why is ZonedDate absent in NodaTime?

Tags: nodatime

I am exploring using the NodaTime library, but am a bit perplexed that both  LocalDate and ZonedDateTime types are provided, but there is no ZonedDate.  Since the api appears to be carefully thought through, I suspect this is not a mere oversight.  I can certainly use a ZonedDateTime with a zero time portion, but thought I would ask before going too far down that road.

Comment: Basically we haven't seen enough evidence that it would be useful, in terms of use cases served etc. There's a feature request at https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/1192 that you could add information to in terms of how you'd expect to use it.